# How to restrict returned Wordpress REST-API fields when using WP-API Node Module

Tags: wordpress-rest-api, wp-api

If I call this Wordpress blog url in a browser

```
<root...>wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=5&fields=id,link,title
```

I get back JSON and the result is restricted to 3 fields

**So how can I do this when using the node js wp-api module?**

I would like something similar to .fields([]) but there is nothing in the docs, can find nothing in the module code.
TypeError: wpapi.posts(...).perPage(...).fields is not a function

Or something like .filter({})
TypeError: wpapi.posts(...).perPage(...).filter is not a function
But I think this might be connected with another Wordpress plugin that's required.

```
        wpapi.posts()
            .perPage(5)
            .fields(['id','link','title'])
            .search( 'search-term' ) //= (search in title or content)
            .filter({
                category_name: 'islands',
                fields: [ 'id','link','title' ]
            })
            .get(function (err, data) {
```

..... etc.

TypeError: wpapi.posts(...).perPage(...).fields is not a function

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears wp-api node module does not allow this.

So I uninstalled it and am now using axios along with standard text urls.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
wpapi.posts().param('_fields', 'id,title,content').get()
```

The [node-wpapi documentation](https://github.com/WP-API/node-wpapi) seems to suggest say that `perPage()` and functions like it are convenience functions that call `param(props, value)`.

```
wpapi.posts().param('_fields', ['id','title','content']).get()
```

also seems to work but the first option gives a resulting request url that looks more like the format the [Wordpress REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) uses